# Select max value AND the corresponding row id grouped by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, group-by

I have a (mssql) *ranking list table* which has an *id*, a *username*, a *date* and a *score* attribute.

```
id | username | date | score
----------------------------
1      joe    01/2020  200
2      bob    01/2020  300
3      max    02/2020  350
4      jane   02/2020  300
5      bob    02/2020  250
6      joe    03/2020  150
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to select the highest score grouped by date with the corresponding id and username, which would produce a result like the following:

```
id | username | date | score
----------------------------
2      bob    01/2020  300
3      max    02/2020  350
6      joe    03/2020  150
```

I'm by no means a database guy and I failed miserably!

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Edit: I don't care about ties at this point.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What if you have ties?

Comment: It's a mssql database. (I just changed the tags.) At this point I don't care about ties. I need one user (with the highest score) per date even if there are actually more users with the same score at this date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your database supports window functions:

```
Select * from (Select t.*,
row_number() OVER (Partition by date order by score desc)  rn
from table t) where rn = 1;


+----+----------+---------+-------+----+
| id | username | dte     | score | rn |
+----+----------+---------+-------+----+
|  2 | bob      | 01/2020 |   300 |  1 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+----+
|  3 | max      | 02/2020 |   350 |  1 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+----+
|  6 | joe      | 03/2020 |   150 |  1 |
+----+----------+---------+-------+----+
```

Comment: I followed your lead and it worked out for me! Thanks!
As I work with a mssql database I had to tweak your query just a bit:
Select * from (Select t.*,
row_number() OVER (Partition by date order by score desc) rn
from score_table t) as tmp where tmp.rn = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
select a.* form table_name a
where a.score=( select max(score) from table_name b where a.date=b.date )
```